# Get a blank page when run "vue serve 'src'" to test single component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

When I run the command "vue serve './src/components/Page/test.vue'" to test my component, I get a blank page, even though it compiles successfully.
I configured script "page:test": "vue serve ./src/components/Page/test.vue" in package.json. Then I run "npm run page:test" in terminal.But wehen i open the page in live server,there's nothing on page.The output information of the terminal is as follows.

It doesn't seem to run the "cli-service-global" I installed globally

```
> my-site@0.1.0 page:test
> vue serve ./src/components/Page/test.vue
Runing npm run serve ./src/components/Page/test.vue
> my-site@0.1.0 page:test
> vue-cli-service serve ./src/components/Page/test.vue
```

How can i resolve this problem?